# Webpack warning - There is another module with an equal name when case is ignored

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack is giving these warnings in the browser console.

[image]

I am unable to find the module names given in warning in my application. Also I have scanned through all the files in my application if I have a reference of module with different cases as mentioned on github issue like [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/382) and [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/435), .
There is no obvious way to dignose which module is causing these warnings.

Any ideas to detect and eradicate these warnings?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem where it's showing a relative path for the first warning and an absolute path for the second. `WARNING in ./~/lodash/_coreJsData.js` and `WARNING in C:/[an absolute path]/~/lodash/_coreJsData.js`. Were you able to resolve or at least debug the issue? For me it seems restricted to `webpack-dev-middleware` as I do not receive warnings when using `webpack` directly.

Comment: Haven't got at the bottom of it yet :(

Comment: I was able to solve it on my side. I'm running on windows of all things the drive letter casing on the command line caused the problem to occur. Literally `C:\ ` (works)  vs `c:\ ` (broken). https://twitter.com/brandonjboone/status/741428564118097920

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the path you enter the node project,

d:/foo to D:/foo,

check the issue here [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2362)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Lin's answer's link, if you have a shortcut to the Command Prompt that uses capital C, this problem arises. I changed my shortcut to lowercase c and then it works.